# Microsoft Graph API: A specific users e-mail activity to other users in my organization

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

For research purposes, I am interested to know whether the Microsoft Graph API can provide information on the e-mail activity of individual users in my organization, in terms of how many e-mails one user has sent to another, specific user?

My goal is to create a directed Graph, where the nodes are the individuals in my organizations, and the edges a weighted in terms of how many e-mails one user has sent to another user.

It would also be of interested if this can be done through the Microsoft 365 report.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in terms of how many e-mails one user has sent to another, specific user?

Because that is a very specific metric it doesn't you can get a broad-based report of email activity using the reports endpoint. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getemailactivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-10145 eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getEmailActivityUserDetail(period='D30')
```

would give the last 30 days of email activity.

If you really need the metric you want then you can always access the underlying data from the Mailbox using the Graph eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?Search="(Participants:user@domain.com)"
```

or other combination of filters